# how to encode existing mysql data latin1 to utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, collation

In the past, my DB collation and table were latin1 or like this. And stored some data on my database.

But recently changed My DB collation UTF8 and table utf8_general_ci, but my previous data still latin1.

I want to convert my existing table data to utf8_general_ci. How to??

Comment: Why would you want to convert to `utf8_general_ci`. If you want to use UTF-8 you must use `utf8mb4_general_ci` instead.

Comment: Seems like there is no easy way to do such a work. You must create another table with chosen encodeing pattern and then insert data into it. At last, you may need change this new table's name to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any "problems"?  The encoding of a column and the encoding in the client do not have to be the same; MySQL will convert on the fly.

If you want to add Asian characters or Emoji, then you do need utf8mb4 (or at least utf8).  Before embarking on a conversion, please discuss the scope of the problem.  In particular, if you are seeing 'garbage', look at [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for diagnosing the problem.

Assuming you have correctly encoded data in your table,

```
ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Here are 7 possible cases; you seem to have the first case:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

If you have already stored, say, Emoji in the latin1 column, you have a worse mess; we need to discuss further.

Terminology:

- The `CHARACTER SET` is what bits are used to *encode* characters.  Eg: latin1, utf8, utf8mb4.
- The `COLLATION` is how characters are *compared*, as for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.  Eg: latin1_general_ci, utf8_general_ci, utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

`latin1` can handle all Western European characters.
`utf8` can handle most characters worldwide.
`utf8mb4` is a superset of `utf8`, and is needed for Emoji and some Chinese characters.